# Matplotlib Horizontal Gradient

Tags: python, matplotlib

The cmap gradient seems to apply vertically. Is there a way to apply the gradient horizontally? Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate data...
x = 25, 32, 18, 21, 28, 22, 29, 31
y = 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5

# Plot...
plt.scatter(x, y, c=y, s=500, cmap='RdYlGn', alpha=0.8)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The cmap gradient seems to apply vertically. Is there a way to apply the gradient horizontally?

There is, and it is as simple as setting `c=x`, as per [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter) and [the source](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/axes/_axes.html#Axes.scatter).

For example, from,

```
x = 25, 32, 18, 21, 28, 22, 29, 31
y = 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5

plt.scatter(x, y, c=y, s=500, cmap='RdYlGn', alpha=0.8)
```

And,

[image: From]

To,

```
x = 25, 32, 18, 21, 28, 22, 29, 31
y = 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5

plt.scatter(x, y, c=x, s=500, cmap='RdYlGn', alpha=0.8)
```

And,

[image: To]